# Using Interlocked.CompareExchange() operation on a bool value?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two questions:

1. Is there a need to use Interlocked class for accessing boolean values? Isn't a read or a write to a boolean value atomic by default?
2. I tried using Interlocked.CompareExchange on a boolean and got the following error:

   ```
    bool value = true;
    Interlocked.CompareExchange<bool>(ref value, false, true);
   ```

   Error: The type 'bool' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref T, T, T)'

How do I go about solving this problem?

Comment: your question fails to mention the magic 'threading' word anywhere. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. Reading or writing boolean values separately **is** atomic, but "compare and exchange" does both reading and writing to the same address, which means that entire transaction is **not** atomic. If multiple threads can write to this same location, you need to make the entire transaction atomic, by using the `Interlocked` class.
2. `public static T CompareExchange<T>(ref T a, T b, T c)) where T : class` overload can only be used with reference types (note the `where T : class` clause at the end). Instead of a boolean value, you can use the `CompareExchange(Int32, Int32, Int32)` overload, and switch the boolean with an `Int32`.

   Alternatively, if you want to keep your variables of boolean type, you can use the `lock` method to ensure thread safety. This would be a *slightly* slower solution, but depending on your performance requirements, this might be still the preferred way.

Answer (score 19):

You can use [Interlocked.Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.exchange) on an `int` for this:

```
using System.Threading;

// ...

int boolValue = 0; // Start False

// ...

if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref boolValue, 1) == 1) // Set to True
{
    // Was True
}
else
{
    // Was False                
}
```

Answer (score 14):

**Roll your own "AtomicBoolean" class** (that wraps `Interlocked.CompareExchange(...)`)

```
using System.Threading;

public class AtomicBoolean
{
    private const int TRUE_VALUE = 1;
    private const int FALSE_VALUE = 0;
    private int zeroOrOne = FALSE_VALUE;

    public AtomicBoolean()
        : this(false)
    { }

    public AtomicBoolean(bool initialValue)
    {
        this.Value = initialValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides (non-thread-safe) access to the backing value
    /// </summary>
    public bool Value
    {
        get
        {
            return zeroOrOne == TRUE_VALUE;
        }
        set
        {
            zeroOrOne = (value ? TRUE_VALUE : FALSE_VALUE);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempt changing the backing value from true to false.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Whether the value was (atomically) changed from false to true.</returns>
    public bool FalseToTrue()
    {
        return SetWhen(true, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempt changing the backing value from false to true.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Whether the value was (atomically) changed from true to false.</returns>
    public bool TrueToFalse()
    {
        return SetWhen(false, true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempt changing from "whenValue" to "setToValue".
    /// Fails if this.Value is not "whenValue".
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="setToValue"></param>
    /// <param name="whenValue"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool SetWhen(bool setToValue, bool whenValue)
    {
        int comparand = whenValue ? TRUE_VALUE : FALSE_VALUE;
        int result = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref zeroOrOne, (setToValue ? TRUE_VALUE : FALSE_VALUE), comparand);
        bool originalValue = result == TRUE_VALUE;
        return originalValue == whenValue;
    }
}
```

---

**Example Usage**:

```
class MultithreadedClass
{
    private AtomicBoolean isUpdating = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public void Update()
    {
        if (!this.isUpdating.FalseToTrue())
        {
            return; //a different thread is already updating
        }
        try
        {
            //... do update.
        }
        finally
        {
            this.isUpdating.Value = false; //we are done updating
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Test cases** (if you're going to use it in production):

```
[TestClass]
public class AtomicBooleanTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestAtomicBoolean()
    {
        AtomicBoolean b = new AtomicBoolean();
        Assert.IsFalse(b.Value);

        b = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        Assert.IsFalse(b.Value);

        b = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        Assert.IsTrue(b.Value);

        //when Value is already true, FalseToTrue fails
        b.Value = true;
        Assert.IsFalse(b.FalseToTrue());
        Assert.IsTrue(b.Value);

        //when Value is already false, TrueToFalse fails
        b.Value = false;
        Assert.IsFalse(b.TrueToFalse());
        Assert.IsFalse(b.Value);

        //Value not changed if SetWhen fails
        b.Value = false;
        Assert.IsFalse(b.SetWhen(true, true));
        Assert.IsFalse(b.Value);

        //Value not changed if SetWhen fails
        b.Value = true;
        Assert.IsFalse(b.SetWhen(false, false));
        Assert.IsTrue(b.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems a bit overcomplicated.  How about having an `AtomicBoolean` class with a single static instance `Truth`, and interpreting any reference to `Truth` as true, and any other reference as false?

Comment: @supercat Updated to include an example of how I would use it; I think the use-case isn't too complicated. What I was going for is a boolean wrapper with atomic operations. What I think you're suggesting might work better with enums -- perhaps as part of a finite state machine (where changing between states needs to be atomic).

Comment: My point was that if one defines `AtomicBoolean` as a class without a public constructor but with widening typecasts to and from `bool` (where `true` is a reference to the only instance that will ever exist and `false` is null) the `Interlocked` methods in the framework will work *as-is* with the expected semantics.  Each *variable* of type `AtomicBoolean` will encapsulate an atomic `boolean` state, thus behaving as a variable of type `Bool` except for the lack of a public constructor.  If `AtomicBool` wraps an `Integer`, each variable will encapsulate not an atomic state, but instead...

Comment: ...the *identity* of an object which holds an atomic Boolean state; if two variables hold references to the same instance, then an atomic operation performed on one will affect the state reported by both (since both variables would report the state of the same instance).

Comment: Oh, I see... your goal is to use the `Interlocked` API directly. (I don't particularly like that API, so I wrote wrapper methods around it.) Regardless, the bool type-casts would definitely help with the semantics of using one. But I would probably implement a "False" singleton to correspond to the "Truth" singleton. (And probably use  protected constructors so that unit-tests won't be a burden.)

Comment: I would use `null` for false rather than a `Falsity` singleton so that there will only be two values an `AtomicBool` can hold: null or `Truth`.  Allowing multiple `false` values would make the thing behave a little more like `bool` in most ways (e.g. `foo = new AtomicBool()` would set `foo` to false) but would make `Interlocked.CompareExchange` behave oddly if an object held a false value which was different from the one passed as a comparand.

Comment: If this is done at all, it should be done as a `struct`.

Comment: One comment (a year and a half later): As I understand the .NET memory model, you'll want to use `Interlocked.Exchange` in your Value setter, or else other threads are not guaranteed to see the written value immediately.  Alternately, you could mark `zeroOrOne` as `volatile`.

Comment: Thread-safety issues are noted in the property comment, but I don't remember why I didn't use ".Exchange" originally in the setter. Thanks.

Comment: Will it ever work? My guess that if you extract Interlocked into separate method\class the operation will not longer be interlocked. Сompiler needs to call chain of methods and pass result down the call stack. At this time another thread will sneak in.

Comment: The example doesn't seem correct, finally block will set the flag to false for everyone, even if it's not acquired.

Comment: Groo, are you sure about that? :)

Answer (score 10):

You can't use interlocked for Boolean. You're better off using an int instead.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/98293/interlocked-compareexchange-should-offer-an-overload-for-boolean